# Order dependencies between binary variables

Tags: random-variable, binary-data, independence

I have a series of random, binary variables that are sampled in a particular order. Some may be affected by the order in which they're sampled, i.e. there may be order dependencies. Suppose I sample them a large number of times in random orders and record their outcomes. What would be the best way to quantify the degree to which one given variable is dependent on another being sampled before it?

I have considered concepts such as conditional entropy but am not particularly well-versed in this area so some advice regarding the best way to do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: This question is intriguing but needs more detail to be answerable. Could you tell us more about the source of the information and how the order dependencies have evolved? Would it be possible to share a sample of the data you intend to analyze? What methodological approaches have you considered, even if only in the back of your mind. There are many possible dependence metrics, statistical and information theoretic, conditional entropy is only one of them. Tetrachoric correlations are appropriate for binary data. Structuring the analysis seems the biggest issue, perhaps a variant of SPRT?

Comment: The variables are modelling the outcomes of software tests (pass or fail). In software testing, there is a problem known as test flakiness, i.e. non-determinism in the outcomes of tests. This can be due to a variety of reasons, one of which is test order dependency. This arises when tests alter the state of a program (or make an external change, i.e. modifying a file), impacting the outcomes of other tests. This is considered bad, but is a fairly common problem and is what I'm trying to investigate.

Comment: Idk...still sounds pretty vague. Economists might describe it as *path dependence*. Why wouldn't a sequential test (e.g., SPRT -- *sequential probability ratio test*) of some kind work? *Granger causality* is a weak test for causal dependence between time series (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality), maybe a methodological variant of that can be lifted and made to work. You should take it as a learning experience that this question is getting views but no one seems to know what to do with it, including me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the abstract from a talk given by Yash Deshpande, MIT:

> > Title: Statistical Inference with Adaptively Collected Data
>
> Abstract:
>
> Modern experimentation, data collection and modeling is often adaptive
>   – the insight gleaned from prior data informs and influences the data
>   collected in the future. While this adaptivity is practically useful,
>   the correlations it induces in data are problematic for inference.
>   Indeed, classical methods for computing uncertainty estimates like
>   confidence intervals and p-values can be misleading in the presence of
>   such correlations.
>
> In this talk, I will focus on multi-armed bandits, an illustrative
>   example of adaptive data collection. I will discuss a general
>   algorithmic procedure that ‘debiases’ estimators computed on data
>   collected by bandit algorithms, thereby allowing to compute confidence
>   intervals and p-values in the standard fashion. The procedure is
>   efficient computationally and the resulting uncertainty estimates are
>   near-optimal. Time permitting, I will also discuss extensions to
>   bandits with covariates and the high-dimensional or ‘data-poor,
>   feature-rich’ regime.

This sounds like it might have relevance for your question. Deshpande has several ungated papers with further elucidation.

FYI...